# animating a uicollectionviewcell, text alignment off center during animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, animatewithduration

I am animating a `UICollectionViewCell` to shrink when tapped. The animation works, however it seems the text is moving to the left and the animating towards the center over the duration i've set (0.3 seconds in this case). I have tried a few variations of the animation procedure, but the situation remains.

Here is an example of the text issue:

[image]

And the code implementation:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var currentCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell!

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {

      currentCell.backgroundColor = self.categoryArray[indexPath.row].catColor
      currentCell.frame.inset(dx: 5, dy: 5)

      let imageView: UIImageView = currentCell.subviews[0] as UIImageView
      let imageSize = currentCell.frame.height * 0.45
      imageView.frame = CGRect(x: (currentCell.frame.width / 2) - (imageSize / 2), y:currentCell.frame.height * 0.15, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)

      let textLabel:UILabel! = currentCell.subviews[2] as UILabel
      textLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: currentCell.frame.height * 0.30, width: currentCell.frame.width, height: currentCell.frame.height)

      let bottomBorder: UIView = currentCell.subviews[1] as UIView
      bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, currentCell.frame.height - 1.0, currentCell.frame.width, 5)

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Ideally I would like the text to resize and stay centered the whole time, instead of "floating" to the left and then move towards the centre

...so many smiley faces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work best by using a CGAffineTransformMakeScale() to change the size of the cell. As far as I know, there's no other way to scale the text in a label in an animated way.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var currentCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell!
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = self.categoryArray[indexPath.row].catColor
        currentCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)
    })

}
```

Comment: oh my gosh, `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` is incredible! Thanks!

Comment: @zillaofthegods, yeah, it makes things a lot easier if you're trying to scale a whole view with multiple subviews.